# Xpages no results after FTSearch on view

Tags: view, xpages

I have a search module in my application which filters multiple views, depending on the user choice.

I want to add a dialog if the search has no results, instead of showing the view empty. How can I do this?

I have tried to get rowCount() but it seems it is not getting the right number of rows, I don't know why.

SSJS code:

```
var vw=database.getView("vwCautareDocI");
var tmpArray = new Array("");
var cTerms = 0; 
var dateFormatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat( "MM-dd-yyyy" ); 

if (sessionScope.numprenum) { 
   tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(Field NumePrenume = \"*" + sessionScope.numprenum + "*\")"; 
} 

if (sessionScope.postvizat) { 
   tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(Field PostulVizat = \"*" + sessionScope.postvizat + "*\")"; 
} 

if (sessionScope.din && sessionScope.pana) {
    tmpArray[cTerms++] = "Field _creationDate >= " + dateFormatter.format(sessionScope.din) + " AND Field _creationDate <= " + dateFormatter.format(sessionScope.pana);
}


filter = tmpArray.join(" AND ").trim(); 
var vec=vw.getAllDocumentsByKey(filter , true);
return vec.getCount();
```

This is the filter I use to filter my view. I wanted to add this code to a button, and if the result is 0 then instead of showing the view, it should show a dialog with a message.

Answer (score 0):

`getAllDocumentsByKey` and `fTSearch` methods do different things on the view. You're trying to return the number of entries where the first column matches the full text search criteria you're using. I suspect the view is not categorised on that criteria.

Comment: Which would be the aproach to do both ftSearch and return the filtered docs?

Comment: You're looking for just the outcome of an ftsearch, not a filter. So vw.ftSearch() is the method you want, not getAllDocumentsByKey(). Also, getCount() has bad performance. If you want to check whether there are any results, call getFirstDocument() on the NotesDocumentCollection that results from the ftSearch and check whether or not it's null. The code block you have returns a number, not the results of the ftSearch. You'll need to return the NotesDocumentCollection to get those.