# Show message if there is no result when search the view

Tags: xpages

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973155/xpages-no-results-after-ftsearch-on-view) 
is very similar to what I would like to ask. However, I tried to solve my problem using the solution from that post but not successful. I realize I cannot ask question in that post. So I would post here with my code. (please note, if it is not appropriate to create a new post, please remove it)

In the application, the user is able to search, when the user clicks a button, it will redirect the user the result page.

In the result page, there is a computed field and a view. The computed field is used to show message if there is no result in the view after search. If the result matches to user's criteria, the view will display the result.

The view works fine when the result matches to user's selection, but if no result matches to user's selection, it only displays the view column header. Therefore I would like to use a computed field to show a message to notify the user that the search function is performed and no result return. Otherwise, the user will not know their search has no result return.

Here is the code of the result page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1"></xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>

<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" style="margin-left:200.0px">     </xp:text>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:viewPanel id="viewPanel4" viewStyle="width:600.0px;background- color:rgb(255,255,255);margin-left:200.0px" rows="15">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view4"
            viewName="OfficerDepLoc">
            <xp:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:var qstring= "";
if ((sessionScope.officerSearch != null && sessionScope.officerSearch != "")|| (sessionScope.depSearch != null && sessionScope.depSearch != "")|| (sessionScope.locSearch != null && sessionScope.locSearch !=""))
{   
    qstring = " ( FIELD officer contains " + sessionScope.officerSearch  + " & FIELD department contains" + sessionScope.depSearch + "& FIELD location contains" + sessionScope.locSearch + ")";
}
var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("",  "myapplication.nsf", false)
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = db.getAllDocuments();
if (dc.getCount() == 0) 
{
    qstring =   getComponent("computedField1").setValue("After search, there is no record found");
}

return qstring;
}]]></xp:this.search>
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Officer" id="viewColumn11">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="officer " id="viewColumnHeader11" sortable="true">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Department" id="viewColumn12">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="department" id="viewColumnHeader12" sortable="true">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Location" id="viewColumn13">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="location" id="viewColumnHeader13" sortable="true">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:this.facets>

        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="footerPager" id="pager5">
        </xp:pager>
    </xp:this.facets></xp:viewPanel>
</xp:view>
```

When I test the page I notice the view does not trigger the computed field to show the message if the search has no result.

I also tried to put this code to the computed field to intend to show the message but it display nothing.

```
var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("",  "myapplication.nsf", false)
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = db.getAllDocuments();
if (dc.getCount() == 0) 
{
    qstring =   getComponent("computedField1").setValue("After search, there is no record found");
}
```

So I would wonder to know how to display the message if the search has no result ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be something like this?

```
<xp:panel id="refreshPanel">
    <xp:viewPanel id="viewPanel4" rendered="getComponent("viewPanel4").getRowCount()>0">
    viewpanel columns
    </xp:viewPanel>
    <xp:panel id="noentriesPanel" rendered="getComponent("viewPanel4").getRowCount()==0">
    text no entries
    </xp:panel>
    </xp:panel>
```

Comment: Franks answer will work, but just thought I'd throw my personal approach into the mix. I always have computed text above my view panel, that computes to something like "Your search "[searchTerm]" returned [getCount] documents"

That way, I only ever need one view panel rendered and if the search is empty the text tells the user there are 0 documents, and if it does return documents, it's nice for the user to see at a glance how many documents are going to be in the view.